# An issue with Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am stuck with JasperReports. I have developed the report using iReport. When I run the report in iReport, it works perfectly. But when I call the report through servlet in my application, for the first call, it works fine. If I call the report second time, it shows as "The Document has No pages" even though my database is having required data. And again if I restart my tomcat server and call the same report, It again works fine. Report giving the problem when I make a second call. Can anyone helps me here?

```
public class Repor extends JFrame {

    HashMap hm = null;
    Connection con = null;
    String reportName;

    public Repor() {
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public Repor(HashMap map) {
        this.hm = map;
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public Repor(HashMap map, Connection con) {
        this.hm = map;
        this.con = con;
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Report Viewer");
    }

    public void setReportName(String rptName) {
        this.reportName = rptName;
    }

    public void callReport() {
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = generateReport();
        JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.add(viewer);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void callConnectionLessReport() {
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = generateEmptyDataSourceReport();
        JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.add(viewer);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void closeReport() {
    }

    /** this method will call the report from data source*/
    public JasperPrint generateReport() {
        try {
            if (con == null) {
                try {
                    con = Database.getConnection();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
            if (hm == null) {
                hm = new HashMap();
            }
            try {
                /**You can also test this line if you want to display 
                 * report from any absolute path other than the project root path*/
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName , hm, con);
            } catch (JRException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jasperPrint;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /** call this method when your report has an empty data source*/
    public JasperPrint generateEmptyDataSourceReport() {
        try {
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
            if (hm == null) {
                hm = new HashMap();
            }
            try {
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName + ".jasper", hm, new JREmptyDataSource());
            } catch (JRException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jasperPrint;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you calling the methods response.getOutputStream().flush(); and close() ? please paste the servlet code

Comment: I have edited my question and added the servlet code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: its not a servlet, its a desktop application.. i never used jasper in this way, sorry, i can not help you